# Pasar codigo de javascript a typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

Estoy queriendo hacer el ojo para validad un password y necesito pasar este codigo a typescript

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHidePassword(ID) {
            if (document.getElementById($("#" + ID).prev().attr('id')).type == "password") {
                $("#" + ID).attr("data-hint", "Hide");
                $("#" + ID).find("i").removeClass("icon-eye").addClass("icon-eye-slash");
                document.getElementById($("#" + ID).prev().attr('id')).type = "text";
            }

            else {
                $("#" + ID).attr("data-hint", "Show");
                $("#" + ID).find("i").removeClass("icon-eye-slash").addClass("icon-eye");
                document.getElementById($("#" + ID).prev().attr('id')).type = "password";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: qué has intentado y qué errores tienes?

Comment: por ahora nada solo queria saber como se podría llegar a integrarar, ya que estoy en un proceso de aprendizaje de angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function ShowHidePassword(ID: number): void {
        if (document.getElementById($("#" + ID).prev().attr('id')).type == "password") {
            $("#" + ID).attr("data-hint", "Hide");
            $("#" + ID).find("i").removeClass("icon-eye").addClass("icon-eye-slash");
            document.getElementById($("#" + ID).prev().attr('id')).type = "text";
        }

        else {
            $("#" + ID).attr("data-hint", "Show");
            $("#" + ID).find("i").removeClass("icon-eye-slash").addClass("icon-eye");
            document.getElementById($("#" + ID).prev().attr('id')).type = "password";
        }
    }
```

Si quieres meter validación de cada campo es otra historia, pero se puede hacer.

Esto es typescript, los cambios son mínimos, al principio, en la declaración de la función forzamos el tipo que retornamos y el tipo de variables que necesitamos.

Comment: si entiendo, mi idea por ahora es no hacer una validación, es solo poder mostrar que cuando uno escribe un password al clickear en el icono del ojo se pueda ver lo que escribió.

Comment: si el código de javascript te funciona, este debe de funcionar también

Comment: esta bien graciass

Comment: Podrias explicar que diferencia hay entre este codigo y el que puso OP? y porque este esta en TS? y cuales son los cambios que hiciste?